# env VAR=VAL command or VAR=VAL command

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

What's really the difference between:

```
env VARIABLE=VALUE command
```

and

```
VARIABLE=VALUE command
```

in bash-compatible shells?

Note: I've done some testing myself and I couldn't see any difference

Edit:
An example would be

```
EDITOR=nano visudo
```

vs

```
env EDITOR=nano visudo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much difference in the result for external commands. Running `env` just involves an additional `exec` to do the variable assignment parsing which the shell would otherwise do. `env -i` would be more useful, since it clears the environment, which isn't that straightforward to do in the shell.

In both cases, expansions like command substitutions `VAR=$(somecmd)` run by the shell before the assignments happen, and both cases follow `PATH` etc. The only difference I can come up with is with the value of the `_`, which [Bash sets to the name of the command it runs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters) (but `env` doesn't). Of course, without `env`, you might also run the shell's builtin version of the command.